How to configure Supabase as a database for a Spring Boot application?
I’m working on a Spring Boot application and I’d like to use Supabase database as my database.
I’ve successfully set up Supabase and created a project, but I’m having trouble configuring it in my Spring Boot application, and also trouble with an endpoint of mine.
My current setup:

Spring Boot version: 3.2.5

What I’ve tried:

Added the necessary PostgreSQL dependencies to my pom.xml:
<dependency> <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId></dependency>

Configured my application.properties with the details provided by Supabase:



spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<supabase-host>:5432/<database-name>
spring.datasource.username=<supabase-user> 
spring.datasource.password=<supabase-password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver


I’m not sure if this configuration is sufficient or if there are additional settings required to fully integrate Supabase with Spring Boot.
I have the backend application deploye on aws elasticbeanstalk and by calling Im getting response status 500, for many attempted request, and then after two/three times, it returs 200.
@GetMapping("/get-all-event")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EventDto>> getAllEvents() {
        List<EventDto> events = eventService.findAllEvent();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(events, OK);
    }


You can try using the connection string of type JDBC. Use either direct connection string or session pooler string.
Remove the username and password fields from your code.
Just this is enough->
spring:
datasource:
url: string as taken from supabase
make sure to include your db password in the connection string
